# Android spinner item selected in cursor displays nothing

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-spinner, android-cursor

What I want is receiving texts from specific number selected in toolbar spinner. But I can't get it displayed in arraylist. If I put text in `equalsIgnoreCase("06123456")` it returns the texts all fine but if I put the string `String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();` in it returns nothing. No errors where found in the logcat. Here is my source code of my spinner and cursor:

```
toolbarSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            write = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            write.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            btnWrite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
            btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String message = write.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            ListView chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat);

            ArrayList<ChatData> listChat = new ArrayList<ChatData>();

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor2 = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
            int indexBody = cursor2.getColumnIndex("body");
            if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor2.moveToFirst()) return;
            while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                do {
                    //display sms inbox by number
                    String number = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("address"));
                    String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    if (number.equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
                        String str = cursor2.getString(indexBody);
                        listChat.add(new ChatData(str, false));
                    }
                } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
            }

            ChatRecAdapter adapter = new ChatRecAdapter(MainActivity.this, listChat);

            chatList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!